# React JS How to change value in @material-ui keyboarddatepicker which is already bound to a model field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

In React JS I  have a dropdown and a @material-ui keyboarddatepicker.
My datepicker is bound to a field in a json file...

```
<div>                    
Expiry Date:<KeyboardDatePicker
id="ExpiryDate"
disablePast 
minDate={new Date()}
format="D/MM/yyyy" 
mask="__/__/____"
value={Person.LocationExpiryDate} 
/>
</div>
```

Note the bound value above from the'Person' model.

I have a dropdown control which on it's onChange event I would like to change the value in the keyboarddatepicker to 6 months hence....

```
{this.DropdownControl(lookups.PracticeLocations, true, Person.CPPEPracticeLocation, event => this.HandleChangePerson(event, 'Location'))}
</div>

HandleChangePerson (event, propertyName) {

if (propertyName == 'Location') {

// Get date 6 months from today
const todayDate =  new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);
const newExpiryDate = moment(todayDate).add(6, 'M').format('D/MM/YYYY') 
// TODO: code here to change the keyboarddatepicker value.

}
```

I've tried using state and  plain js to change the value but because it is already bound it doesn't change the value

I've looked up 'two way binding' but can't seem to find anything that references using a model.

Comment: You need to create an initial state from the model: `const [expiryDate, setExpiryDate] = useState(Person.LocationExpiryDate);`. Now you can use that like `value={expiryDate}` and call `setExpiryDate` to change it. When you're done, you need to send a message up the component tree so the actual person data changes (note that you can also skip the state, but that requires sending `newExpiryDate` up directly so the `Person.LocationExpiryDate` that is passed down changes)

Comment: In case your actual problem is how to send the changed date up the tree: you pass down a setter method as prop, then call it from the child.

Comment: Thank you Chris G, that worked a treat